# Union between View and dymanic SQL query with MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 to try and combine data from a View and a real table, into a temp table. The View BoxAndChannel holds the names of the table I want to combine it with. I have x instances of the same table but with different table names. The schema of the tables are the same.

I have a View that holds the names of the tables and the columns that I need to get. Based upon the values from View BoxAndChannel, I will have to select data from the correct table and column.

**EDIT:**

I want to combine each row from this table **BoxAndChannel**
[image]

With the data from the column as i ColumnName from table as in TableName.

Table1 and Table2 has the same schema and both looks like in the picture below.

**Table1/Table2**

[image]

Hopefully ending up with something like this:

Based on row 1 from BoxAndChannel in the first picture.
[image]

**To sum up:** I have to select each row from BoxAndChannel and then look at the value in TableName and ColumnName and select the values from the table and column with the same name.

Comment: For union you need to have same structure in both select query  from your dynamic sql I see only one column this will cause issue in your query .

Comment: for `union` you need same datatype column in same order for it to work. Can you describe your TableName?

Comment: Please paste the  structure of the TableName and why u need a dynamic sql query if you have only one table . It will be helpful if you show your complete query so that it can be answered accordingly .

Comment: You are mixing standard sql and dynamic sql in the same query. You can't do this quite like you are trying. You will have to do this entire thing as dynamic sql. I would ask the question though why you have table and column names in a table like this. It is a red flag that something is off with the design. You are going to have to provide some details if you want a real answer here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly in one query.  Copying it to a temp table is probably one of your better bets.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE ( col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT )

INSERT INTO @test
EXEC sp_executesql N'select 1, 2, 3'

SELECT 4, 5, 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @test
```